# How to tell if someone is likely to attack?

Tags: dwarf-fortress, dwarf-fortress-adventure

There've been a few situations in Adventurer mode when I've been wandering through the wilderness, and have been stopped by a group of heavily armed people. At first they just call out a greeting but then, sometimes, they initiate combat once I start to move away from them.

There's also been an occasion or two when I've found a lone person in the wilderness and started a conversation with them, only to have it cut short by one of my allies/followers attacking them.

**Is there any indication if (and why) someone will attack?**

Comment: Is "The default state of mind of a dwarf is 'Madness'" explanatory enough?

Comment: This happens to me often too. I was exploring a monastery, talking to the locals all peacefully until I'd enter a crowded room, where random guys started attacking me. The only way to be certain is to run a legends viewer alongside your game and look up any civs or entities and see if they are in hostile relations with your adventurer and their civ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there's not a good way to tell this. In general, if you're using travel mode and a group stops you, they're going to be hostile (even if sometimes they seem like they're not).

Also, if they're at a campsite they're probably bandits. I've been to campsites where the bandits are totally neutral towards me, but if I have a companion from an entity they're enemies with a fight will start.

It's generally possible to have a conversation with intelligent hostiles before a combat starts, which makes it even harder to tell what's going on! You can try to ask questions about the area or the local ruler to identify which entity they're a part of (if you're at a campsite and they're telling you that they're in charge and they're right in all things, it means they're their own entity). However, this isn't very useful when you meet a traveller who tells you that they're on a secret mission, and to ask you about the area when they get home.

The yielding/combat escalation system can lead to some weird situations where your yielded enemies will only spit at you and call you a murderer, but they're happy to join you for adventure.

I personally find the most reliable way to tell if a group is hostile is to take good companions with me and be ready for a fight. As you discovered, companions are particularly good at detecting enemies, usually by starting a fight with them!

Comment: I find the most reliable way to tell if a group is hostile is to murder them all viciously and assume they were hostile.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure a sure-fire way of *knowing* if an enemy is going to attack in travel mode, but every time I've been stopped by a group of travelers and every time there's a notification that says "You feel uneasy", they've attacked me.

Every time I've been a human and fought a traveler, I've lost. Mostly because they either out-number or out-maneuver me. As a suggestion, if you want a major step up and a head-start in your physical capabilities, I suggest becoming a vampire. But before you start drinking blood of the undead, you really want to read up on not just vampires, but on the undead. Depending on your play style, you might want to read up on about not just being a vampire, but in general being one of the undead, because they all have their perks. (But I think vampires are the best of the bunch, and might have the least amount of perks.)